# NullPointerException is thrown when thread.join() is used

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I have created a class for matrix multiplication that implements the Runnable interface. It has an array of threads which are all initialized, and to ensure all calculations are done before returning the matrix I used a for each loop for the same array of Threads and a NullpointerException is fired right when trying to join the first thread. Do thread objects turn into null after they are done with the process?

I added an if clause to check if the thread is null it solved the problem but I haven't found any indication that a thread object turns to null after done.

```java
Thread[] threads = new Thread[amountOfThreads];
for (Thread thread : threads) {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
for (Thread thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```

Comment: Long story short: `thread = new Thread(this)` does **not** assign the value to the array. After the loop, your array will still only contain `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add created thread to your array. Like this

```java
Thread[] threads = new Thread[amountOfThreads];
int i=0;
for (Thread thread : threads) {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    threads[i++] = thread;
}
for (Thread thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```